# SIGABRT called when calling find() on a string element in an array

Tags: c++, string

Here is the code I have:

```
string words[n];
 .
 .
 .
 for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); j++){
            if(words[j].find(new_word) != std::string::npos){...} //abort(3) called
 }
```

However, SIGABRT isn't called in the same code when I call find on a normal string, like

```
  for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); j++){
            if(s.find(new_word) != std::string::npos){...} //abort(3) NOT called
```

Why is this behavior happening? Isn't words[j] referring to a string element?
Edit: adding the entire code, in case the snippet isn't sufficient :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while (T--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        string words[n];
        for(int i =0; i<n;i++){
            cin>>words[i];
        }
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        string new_word;
        //start inserting spaces now
        for(int i =1;i<=s.length();i++){
            new_word = s.substr(0,i);
            //cout<<s<<endl;
            //start scanning
            for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); j++){
                if(words[j].find(new_word) != std::string::npos){
                    s = s.erase(s.find(new_word), new_word.length());
                }
            }
        }
        if(s.length() == 0)
            cout<<"1"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"0"<<endl ;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Edit 2: The question is here :http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/word-break/0

Comment: Hard to say. Please, try to reproduce with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Probably, missing context may be the actual reason for the observed behavior.

Comment: @Scheff, I've added the code now.

Comment: If the declaration is `std::string words[n]` then the expression `words[j]` refers to the array subscript but not the overloaded operator `std::string::operator[]()`. To convince yourself, you could do `words[j][0]` which refers to the first element (character) in `words[j]`.

Comment: `int n; cin << n; string words[n];` means you're working with a variable length array. This is supported in C11 but not in C++. If it works this is a proprietary extension of the compiler but I wouldn't count on it. In this case, `std::vector<std::string> words;` is a proper C++ replacement.

Comment: Are you sure that `string words[n]` does a proper construction of all elements? In opposition, `std::vector<std::string> words(n);` would grant this.

Comment: @Scheff "This is supported in C11" Well... sort of supported. It was made optional in C11. Check for `__STDC_NO_VLA__` before you try to use it.

Comment: Probably your error: `for(int i =1;i<=s.length();i++)` allows `i` to reach `s.length()` which is out of range for `s`.

Comment: @user4581301 But there is no `s[i]` access.

Comment: @user4581301 This was alerting me too but: The only use of `i` is as 2nd arg. of `std::string::substr()`. The default is `npos` and this does limit the sub-string to `std::string::size()`. Thus, it shouldn't be _the_ cause of sigabort...

Comment: @Scheff. You're right. I'm on crack.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it. Additionally, `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` are deprecated C-compatibility headers, always use `cstdlib` and `cstdio` respectively instead.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output. The question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: @tambre, thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I've added the original question.

Comment: @Scheff, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "If the declaration is std::string words[n] then the expression words[j] refers to the array subscript but not the overloaded operator std::string::operator[]().". I tried deleting my code and using words[1].find(), and no error was thrown.

Comment: @aeye Never include code, input or output as pictures (accessibility problems) or on an external site (the site may go down), instead include it in the question and format it as a code block. Questions doing including any part of them on an external site are off-topic according to the rules.

Comment: I tried to answer your specific question "Isn't words[j] referring to a string element?" Yes, for declaration `string words[n];` `words[j]` is referring to the element j which is of type `string` (i.e. `operator[]` returns `string&`).

Comment: I don't know how `words[j].find(new_word) != std::string::npos` blows up, but   it could prevent a call to `s = s.erase(s.find(new_word), new_word.length())` [which blows up really easy](https://ideone.com/Op47nZ). Not so useful without an answer though, and I couldn't for the life of me figure out from the code what the goal was.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm really, really sorry for the horrible code. I'm still learning.  The main goal of the program is, given an array that contains several words [I like xyz] and a string [ilike] is it possible to split the string such that the words are contained in the array.  My approach was to iterate through the string, separate letters, first one, then 2, then 3, and keep checking if any match is found in the array. If it is found, it is deleted from the string.

Comment: I got that from the link you posted, which is why I commented on it. Things to try and prevent confusion: better problem description up front so readers know what the code is supposed to do. Better variable names to that readers know what the variable represents and can infer how it is supposed to be transformed and used.

Comment: Keywords: "backtracking" and "recursion". Say you have a function that removes word to remove from the front of a string to be parsed. If  string to be parsed is now empty, return true. Otherwise, check to see if any of a list of strings is at the front of string to be parsed. If yes return the result of calling the function again with string to be parsed and the word that was found because it needs to be removed, if no, return false.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple why it's crashing when you change that line.  In the version that crashes you check whether `words[j].find(new_word)` is equal to `std::string::npos` and then call `s.erase(s.find(new_word), ...)`.  Of course, `s.find(new_word)` could still be `std::string::npos`, and [string::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) throws an exception when the first argument is out of range.  In the version that you say does not crash, you correctly check whether `s.find(new_word)` is `std::string::npos` before passing it to `s.erase`.  It actually has nothing to do with whether you're using a string in an array or not.

Be it known, though, the variable length array `string words[n]` is not standard c++, it's a GCC extension, and so you have to look to them for documentation as to whether all strings are initialized and and whatnot.  The standard C++ way to make that array would be `string *words = new string[n]` followed by `delete[] words` to free the memory.  If you do that, `sizeof(words)` will be the size of a string pointer, not the allocated size of the array, so you would have to use `n` instead of `sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0])`.  The current best-practice would be to use a `shared_ptr<string>` or a `unique_ptr<string>` and `make_shared` or `make_unique` depending on whether or not you will have multiple aliases to the array.  If you use those, you do not have to call `delete` (or `new` for that matter); the memory will be freed correctly and automatically when the `*_ptr` objects go out of scope.